# Confused with apache and tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, tomcat

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I have both Tomcat and Apache running.  So when I point to `localhost`, I can see the page loading with welcome page.

Does `localhost` refer to Tomcat or Apache?

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat) for some great information on a 'Tomcat vs. Apache' style question over at stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is a http server while Tomcat is a jsp/servlet container. when you type `localhost:80` then it is Apache server and if you type `localhost:8080` then it is Tomcat server.

The default port for Apache is 80 and for Tomcat is 8080, if you have not changed anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is Apache. Tomcat is at

```
localhost:8080.
```

Comment: So what is the diff between `localhost` and `localhost:8080`?

Comment: Simply if you type localhost it means localhost:80, both have different port address.